# Loop over a single column condition statement in awk

Tags: loops, if-statement, awk, gawk

I want to print a line if a statement is true, but I want to loop through several variations.  This is works as a batch script:

```
Awk "($9==1) {print $0}" file > out.txt & type out.txt >> all_out.txt
Awk "($9==3) {print $0}" file > out.txt & type out.txt >> all_out.txt
Awk "($9==5) {print $0}" file > out.txt & type out.txt >> all_out.txt
```

But not very elegant. Can this be written into a for loop or if statement? I'm using gnuawk on windows with cygwin installed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
awk '($9==1) || ($9==3) || ($9==5)' Input_file  > all_out.txt
```

OR

```
awk '($9%2 != 0)' Input_file  > all_out.txt
```

Considering that you want to take all conditions output into a single file here, let me know if this is not the case.

Comment: That's a much neater 1 liner thanks! But what if I need to go from 1,3,5 up to 101 for example . Do you have any idea's?  Maybe using i++?

Comment: Is there any pattern that you need to check for example all odd values from 1 to 200 etc etc or something else here?

Comment: Yes, I would like odd values of the ninth column. And I need it to be flexible to go up to high numbers. So for example setting a value like x=200  at the start of a script.

Comment: I edited my code, which will check only odd numbers of $9, let me know if this helps you.

Comment: `^1` for the 2nd script. The first one should just be `awk '$9 ~ /^[135]$/' file`.

Comment: Thank you Ed for encouraging :)

Comment: Yes. That's it! Can you tell me what %2 does? I guess if I was to swap to evens on the ninth column !=0  becomes !=1?

Comment: % is a MOD operator, so $9%2 != 0 means if 9%2 is having any mod off then it means it is not fully divided by 2. Which means it can't be even number and we need all odd only as per your question.

Comment: Oh cool. Your answer is perfect. I was just thinking about what it does, how I can use it in other scripts and how to modify it for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$ awk '($9 ~ /^1$|^3$|^5$/) {print $0}' file
```

Comment: Ahem - `($9 ~ /^1$|^3$|^5$/) {print $0}` = `$9 ~ /^[135]$/`.

Comment: @EdMorton - Nice!  I can't compete with you in shortest answer. Thank You :)